# How to send this post without the submit

Tags: http-post

How to send this post without the submit?
I need that as I point to the this html page the form is posted without any button submission.
I am not so expert then please the example should be as simple as possible.
Many thanks for your help.

This is my Post base code:

```html
<html>
<hr>
<b>Send sms text</b>
<br>
<br>
<form method=POST action="http://111.111.111.111:1111/smssend.cgi">
<table>
<tr>
<td> Destination number </td>
<td><input type=text name=num value="+39111111111" </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Message text </td>
<td> <textarea name=text value="My message"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Password </td>
<td> <input type=text name=Pwd value="SMSxxx"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type=submit value=Send>
</form>
<hr>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function send() {
            document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<hr>
<b>Send sms text</b>
<br>
<br>
<form id="myForm" method=POST action="http://111.111.111.111:1111/smssend.cgi">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Destination number</td>
            <td><input type=text name=num value="+39111111111"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Message text</td>
            <td><textarea name=text value="My message"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><input type=text name=Pwd value="SMSxxx"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type=button value=Send onclick="send();">
</form>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```